# how to procedurally generate a disjointed maze in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, procedural-generation

I am creating a game in Unity that is a FPS/Horror game that takes place in the SCP Universe. one of the levels I am making is The Backrooms and I cant find a maze generation algorithm for Disjointed Mazes. Does anyone have an algorithm that would work for this type of project?

Comment: I just finished a Udemy course on this a few months ago. Because this course does cost, I don't think I'm allowed to post their code on a public forum but you can find the course here https://www.udemy.com/share/103NGo3@OgvDuyeMuqI6coBq6rBs80GlH79BL1LKmjfIL4IVEulXXoItuEiDBSVzvb1Rlu5u/

If you're not interested in that, look up Wilsons and Recursive Depth First Search algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

[Using Disjoint Set (Union-Find) to Build a Maze Generator](https://coderscat.com/using-disjoint-set-union-find-to-create-maze/)

```
void rand_maze {
  // begin with a rectangular maze of all closed cells
  // numrows = number of rows of cells;
  // numcols = number of columns of cells;
  start = cell at (0,0);
  goal  = cell at (numrows-1, numcols-1);
  numcells = numrows * numcols;
  Partition p(numcells); // p represents the maze components

  // goal is not reachable from start
  while (!p.Find(start, goal)) {
    edge = randomly select a wall;
    x = edge.x;
    y = edge.y;
    if(!p.Find(x,y)) {
      remove edge;
      // x and y now in same component
      p.Union(x,y);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is close, but when I am implementing this into unity it is not giving me a disjointed maze and is still too closed off for what I am needing it for.